# How can i access specific HTML element based on its type using javascript?

Tags: javascript

if I have multiples html input tags and I want to access those with "radio" type how can i do that using the type?(not by id or name or class). I tried somethings like:
document.getElementsByTagName("input[type='radio']")[0];

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a selector string, you'll have to use `querySelectorAll`, not `getElementsByTagName`.

If you want to select all elements that match the selector string, you also shouldn't look up the array index immediately - instead, store the whole collection.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectoAll("input[type='radio']");

// do stuff with inputs[0], inputs[1], etc
```

In similar situations, if you have a selector string and you only want to use the *first* element that matches it, use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input.someClass');
```